# Form sent to back on interaction with menu item

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu, menuitem

I've got two forms, one being frmMain and the other being frmDatasets. The idea is that frmDatasets is used to manage the application's datasets (it's a program for comparing sorting algorithms).
I have a MenuStrip on frmDatasets with a few items. I just decided to change the Add Dataset item to a drop-down menu with options for loading one from file, or generating one according to certain parameters. All well and good; just add the items, swap some icons around, and change the event handler's signature to handle the right Click event.

Except when I run the program, clicking on the Add Datasets top-level item for the first time sends frmDatasets to the back, displaying an inactive frmMain. Clicking the item again shows the dropdown menu as usual.

If I instead click another top-level menu item, that works just fine. But then simply hovering my mouse over the Add Dataset item causes the 'send to back' thing to happen.

I say "send to back", but it's really just putting it behind frmMain. It remains in front of other windows like Visual Studio and Firefox.

Anyone know what on Earth is going on with this form?

EDIT: If I show frmDatasets as a modal dialog, it stops the whole "sending to back" thing, but I still have to click the menu item twice before it shows the list.

EDIT2: Overriding the onClick event to call mnuAddDatasetDropDown.ShowDropDown removes the double-click issue, but it's only a solution if I keep the form as a modal dialog. Still gets sent to back. Overriding mouseEnter doesn't do anything to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the TopMost property of frmDatasets from its Design view to 'true' fixed all of the problems I was having. No insight as to what was going on, unfortunately, but if anyone else is having this problem then hopefully it'll work for them too.